# extra characters are added to site url

Tags: php, concrete5

Some extra characters are added to the site url (which is under development.concrete5 cms is used). There was no such problem before.

```
 #.UHVsDy7Mja9
```

Is added at the end of every url after loading the page. I have checked the htaccess, header and footer, but can't find any unwanted code there. Is it a spam?

Comment: I noticed one thing there is no such a problem in IE.The problem is in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are probably other "plugins" that do that, a possible candidate is [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com) (if you are using that of course).

AddThis adds a hash-tag to the end of every url for tracking purposes but it can be turned off using (in javascript):

```
var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar": false};
```